# punycode module is deprecated

Tags: nodejs

Al correr mi proyecto de node me sale el siguiente mensaje

> (node:24740) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
> (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)

pero cuando corro el comando

```
node --trace-deprecation punycode
```

Me sale el siguiente error:

> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1152
> throw err;
> ^

> Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\scher\punycode'
> at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:15)
> at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:990:27)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:142:12)
> at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
> code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
> requireStack: []
> }

> Node.js v21.6.1

por lo que no me queda claro que hacer. ¿Cómo podría usar la alternativa que me sugiere el primer warning?

Answer (score 0):

yo tenia el mismo problema pero con nextjs y lo que hice fue borrar la cache en el navegador como ultima opción y me funciono normal. Lo que paso es que se quedo guardado la api con mysql del proyecto pasado con nextjs en el cache del navegador

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).